# Flutter place an object from a stack on top of container outside that stack

Tags: flutter, stack, containers, clip

[image]

Long story short I have a stack, in which I have an image that is position out of the stack.

```
body: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              _positionedImage(),
            ],
          ),
          _bodyContainer(),
        ],
```

container:

```
Widget _bodyContainer() {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 200,
      decoration:  BoxDecoration(
        color: itsyBackground,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(20), topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
        boxShadow: [BoxShadow(offset: Offset(0, 0), color: Colors.green, spreadRadius: 1, blurRadius: 1),],
      ),

        );
  }
```

How can I make so that picture is on top of the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the approach that you used is wrong here.. You don't need a column here. You can simply render a stack an the bottom most widget should be placed first in the stack children.

https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-stack-in-flutter-3264619b3a77

An Example:

```
Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    offset: Offset(0, 0),
                    color: Colors.green,
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                    blurRadius: 1),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: -10,
            child: Image.network(
              'https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-31346158,width-748,height- 
      499,resizemode=4,imgsize-114461/.jpg',
              width: 100,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: my stack also contains other items, in that case how would you make sure that container is placed right after where previous items end?

Comment: As i don't know what you are trying to build using stacks.. this is an awesome article which can help you out.. (kindly upvote the answer, if that help so others don't look into it)

Comment: It did not precisely worked in my case but yes you deserve an upvote and thanks!

Comment: @AleksandreBregadze How did it 'precisely' work for you? My code is identical to the above, but the image isn't showing outside the stack. It clips off, although I have `Clip.none` set

Comment: Place the stack after the widget that clips it that might work. As I understood the positions matter, which goes first and after